# How to rename columns with pattern in R?

Tags: r, rename

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID_1 = 1:5,
ID_2 = 1:5,
ID_3 = 1:5,
ID_4 = 1:5)
```

I want to replace each column with "participantID_" and a digit that has a value of +1 of the digit in the original columns.

As follows:

ID_1 should be participantID_2,
ID_2 should be participantID_3...

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try `colnames(df) = paste0("participantID_", as.numeric(sub(".*_", "", colnames(df)))+1L)`, you may need to adjust the regex.

Comment: What is the logic behind +1? Why start at 2?

Answer (score 2):

`regexpr` to match the number, `regmatches` to extract it, and then overwrite the original `names(df)`:

```
names(df) <- paste0("ParticipantID_",
                    as.numeric(regmatches(names(df), regexpr("\\d$", names(df)))) + 1)
df
#  ParticipantID_2 ParticipantID_3 ParticipantID_4 ParticipantID_5
#1               1               1               1               1
#2               2               2               2               2
#3               3               3               3               3
#4               4               4               4               4
#5               5               5               5               5
```

Comment: `gsub()` might be a more compact option than `regmatches()` + `regexpr()`: `as.numeric(gsub(".*(\\d)$", "\\1", names(df))) + 1`